# How to Get Response from Simple RestKit call with only username and password?

Tags: ios, restkit

Is there a way to get the response back from a extremely basic RestKit call, before making any GETs or POSTs? I'm just extremely confused because I have a bunch of RESTful calls I want to make, but they all require a user_id as a part of the call. How do I get the response from the initial server interaction, which I'm assuming will contain the user_id.

Do we need to build an GET API call that accepts username and password and returns the user_id, or is there a way to do that part through RestKit?  I feel like it should be done through the RestKit client...

UPDATE:
We were missing a needed API call. DOH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand exactly what you want to know:

"Is there a way to get the response back from a extremely basic RestKit call?"
- what is this RestKit call exactly? Every restKit call delegate response or error for you mostly used the following `RKRequestDelegate` methods:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response {
      RKLogInfo(@"Yay! We Got a response"); 
 }
- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error { 
      RKLogInfo(@"Oh no! We encountered an error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }
```

"How do I get the response from the initial server interaction, which I'm assuming will contain the user_id."
What is your initial server interaction exactly and what is the server answer what you receive?
Of course, your server should make this user_id available for you.

Is it maybe a solution for the login process in your case:

Looks like the correct way to configure this is as follows..

```
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://apihost.com" ]; 
objectManager.client.username = @"your-user-name"; 
objectManager.client.password = @"your-password";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. After more research (and banging my head against the wall) we've finally decided that the API call I need just doesn't exist yet.